# Change the width of a popover which has table view in it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I'm trying to achieve two things:

To change the height of the popover to the number of cells in my static table view (which works).

But for the popovers width to be configurable using the storyboard builder.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    CGRect popoverBounds = self.view.frame;

    [self.tableView sizeToFit];

    CGRect newBounds = self.tableView.bounds;
    newBounds.size.width = popoverBounds.size.width;
    self.tableView.bounds = newBounds;

    self.preferredContentSize = self.tableView.contentSize;
}
```

currently this sets the popover to the width of the table view.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is inside this line:

```
self.tableView.bounds = newBounds;
```

You change internal bounds, instead of frame, you need to use:

```
self.tableView.frame = newBounds;
```